# SwiftUI Image picker "Cannot load representation of type public.jpeg"

Tags: swiftui, imagepicker

I have written a ImagePicker for my SwiftUI app, but every time I select an image from my phone, I get an `Cannot load representation of type public.jpeg` error. I've found some articles here on StackOverflow and some other forums where people state that it's a simulator bug, but since I am using my iPhone 13 Pro Max, it has to be something else. Might be of live or raw photos

```
func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
     if let provider = results.first?.itemProvider,
            provider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {
            provider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { [weak self] image, error in
       ...
```

When I check for error, and print out the `localizedDescription` I always get the error above. Any ideas? Thank you

I have also created a custom class:

```
class MyImage: NSObject, NSItemProviderReading {

    let image: UIImage?

    public init(image: UIImage?) {
        self.image = image
    }

    static var readableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider: [String] {
        [
            UTType.image.description,
            UTType.heic.description,
            UTType.rawImage.description,
            UTType.jpeg.description,
            UTType.png.description
        ]
    }

    static func object(withItemProviderData data: Data, typeIdentifier: String) throws -> Self {
        return MyImage(image: UIImage(data: data)) as! Self
    }
}
```

Where as you can see I define all the image types I can think of. It solves the issue in the simulator, where if you pick the red flowers image, it will work, but it still throws the same error when I select a RAW image on my phone.

AFAIK the `UTType.jpeg` is the `public.jpeg` type that should cover this case, but somehow it doesn't.